# In the United States, what are the universities and colleges with the best chess club?

Tags: uscf, clubs

[Webster University](http://www.webster.edu/spice/chess-team/) undeniably takes first place.

But I would like to know more American universities and colleges which have a big chess club.

Comment: There is no best.  Logical fallacy.  There is no way to compare clubs so you can definitively say that A>B>C as you will find examples where A>B>C>A.

Comment: If you go by size then it will only be true at one moment in time as clubs grow and clubs get smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The top four US college chess schools participate in the [Final Four of College Chess](http://www.chessdom.com/final-four-of-college-chess/). This year's (2015) participants were [Webster University](http://www.webster.edu/spice/chess-team/), the [University of Texas at Dallas](http://www.utdallas.edu/chess/), [Texas Tech University](https://www.depts.ttu.edu/ttuchess/), and the [University of Maryland, Baltimore County](http://chess.umbc.edu/). Especially, the University of Texas at Dallas and the University of Maryland, Baltimore County, have consistently had very good results in the [Pan American Intercollegiate Team Chess Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_American_Intercollegiate_Team_Chess_Championship) in the last ten to fifteen years.

You can find other college chess clubs at the [site of the USCF](http://www.uschess.org/content/view/8317/131/).

Comment: Does that make them best?